# Missing SWRL tab in Protege 4

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, swrl, protege4

The protege SWRL tab is not available in Protege 4 versions, I have tried both protege 4.1 and protege 4.2. The axiome plugin mentioned to edit the SWRL rules in protege has been said to work only in protege 3 versions.

Can anyone tell me plugins or procedure to include the plugin to edit SWRL rules in protege?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SWRL rules can be edited in Protégé 4, but not with a nice interface like in Protégé 3. If you go to menu Window -> Views -> Ontology views, there is an option Rules. Select it and add it as a "view", i.e., a rectangle in the current tab. Rules are written like this:

```
parent(?x,?y), brother(?y,?z) -> uncle(?x,?z)
```

where properties are written as binary predicates, classes as unary predicate, variables are prefixed with question marks, head is separated from body by `->` and constants are just written without the ontology prefix. It does not work if the properties, classes and individuals you use are not previously defined in the respective tabs.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ORE ontology rule editor , i am using it and it works well
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ore/

Comment: i downloaded ORE editor but it has no tab for adding swrl rules. it seems it is a tool just for adding rdf triples . how did you add swrl rules using this editor?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Pellet plugin to support SWRL inference in Protege 4.x:

http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/protege/ 
(Reasoning can be started in Reasoner/Start reasoner after selecting Pellet)

This is a very complete tutorial on the integration of Protege 4.x and SWRL:

http://dior.ics.muni.cz/~makub/owl/

Answer (score 0):

now in Protege 5.6.3, SWRL tab works fine.