# SWRL Tab and Jess Tab Support on Protégé 4

Tags: ontology, owl, protege, pellet, protege4

I need to add the SWRL Tab and the Jess Tab to my ontology on Protégé 4 but I could not find any support for Jess. Does Protégé 4 have any support or plugin for Jess, or there is any other substitute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be supported in version 4 but you can still edit swrl rules.

See here: [SWRL tab in Protege 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366438/swrl-tab-in-protege-4)

Answer (score 3):

There is a Pellet plugin to support SWRL inference in Protege 4.x:

http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/protege/ 
(Reasoning can be started in Reasoner/Start reasoner after selecting Pellet)

This is a very complete tutorial on the integration of Protege 4.x and SWRL:

http://dior.ics.muni.cz/~makub/owl/

Answer (score 2):

There is no SWRL tab plugin support after Protege 3.x; rule editor can be enabled using Protege 4 without SWRL tab. please refer the attached image.

[image: Protege 4.2 beta screen shot]